# Java Android - TabLayout and ViewPager2 including the Fragments inside didn't appear

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Im using TabLayout for navigation of the ViewPager2 fragments but the TabLayout and ViewPager2 didnt appear.

ProfileFragments.java:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentProfileBinding binding;

ProfileAdapter profileAdapter;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager2 viewPager2;
private String[] titles = new String[] {"Personal", "Employment", "Education"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager2= (ViewPager2) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);

    profileAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(getParentFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

    viewPager2.setAdapter(profileAdapter);

    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout,viewPager2,((tab,position)-> tab.setText(titles[position]))).attach();

    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    return root;
}}
```

ProfileAdapter.java:

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

private String[] titles = new String[] {"Personal", "Employment", "Education"};

public ProfileAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle){
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position){
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new PersonalFragment();
        case 1:
            return new EmploymentFragment();
        case 2:
            return new EducationFragment();
    }
    return new PersonalFragment();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titles.length;
}}
```

the id for TabLayout and ViewPager2 are tab_layout and view_pager2.

Comment: You do need to use the child `FragmentManager`, like the one Ian had linked you. You're also mixing view/data binding with manual layout inflation, so the `ViewPager2` you're setting the `Adapter` on is not appearing on-screen. Get rid of the manual inflation, and set the `Adapter` on (presumably) `binding.viewPager2`, after the `FragmentProfileBinding.inflate()` call.

Comment: I forgot to mention the `TabLayout` and stuff, but I'm sure you figured out that it moves, too.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry Mr. Mike i dont really figuring out what you told to me. Can you write it down for me in the answer? thanks

Comment: The `FragmentProfileBinding` is meant to replace the `inflater.inflate()` and `view.findViewById()` stuff, so it would end up something like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DnQfo3VGHFCvNBBZeYkwnYvb1bHNdUwF/view?usp=sharing. (Assuming everything built correctly, and that I'm remembering the details correctly.)